# Preview the uploaded pictures in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have implemented a PicturesWall component in my app similar to this one on the antd site: https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-picture-card. When the user uploads images, thumbnails are generated and the user can preview and delete them. Now, this is when I create the item, but I implement an edit functionality where I have the input text fields populated with what the user entered when he created the item. How do I list the images the user uploaded when he created the item?

Answer (score 0):

While editing, you need to update the state of `fileList` and `previewImage` similar to the [`initial state`](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-picture-card) as given below:

```
this.setState({
    fileList:[{uid:-1,status: 'done',url:'your image Url'}],
    previewImage: 'your image Url',
});
```

You can do this by checking if you are getting the image data to be edited.